# Proper syntax for windows functions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following query that works as expected with the base table PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN, however when I LEFT OUTER JOIN it, I am getting lots of duplication and I would like to know if I have the syntax correct as a result of using Windows functions.

The keys between PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN and PS_JOB are EMPLID and EMPL_RCD, so I wouldn't expect there to be duplication, unless I do't have the query formatted correctly.

```
SELECT A.EMPLID, A.EMPL_RCD, EXAM_DT, IMMUN_CODE, RN
FROM ( 
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLID, EXAM_DT, IMMUN_CODE ORDER BY EMPLID DESC) AS RN
            , EMPLID
            , EMPL_RCD
            , EXAM_DT
            , IMMUN_CODE
FROM PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN AS RN1 ) AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_JOB B ON A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID AND A.EMPL_RCD = B.EMPL_RCD 
WHERE A.RN = 1
GROUP BY A.EMPLID,A.EXAM_DT, A.IMMUN_CODE, A.EMPL_RCD, A.RN
ORDER BY A.EXAM_DT
```

Just looking for guidance in terms of whether the query syntax may be formatted incorrectly.

Sample data:

```
EMPLID  EMPL_RCD    EXAM_DT                   IMMUN_CODE    RN
015     1           2018-09-19 00:00:00.000   FLDD          1
015     1           2018-09-19 00:00:00.000   FLDD          1
015     0           2018-09-19 00:00:00.000   FLDD          2
015     0           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   PREV          1
015     1           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   PREV          2
015     1           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   PREV          2
015     1           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   TDAB          1
015     1           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   TDAB          1
015     0           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   TDAB          2
015     0           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   TSPS          1
015     1           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   TSPS          2
015     1           2018-09-20 00:00:00.000   TSPS          2
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and results.  What does duplication look like?

Comment: For every single (EMPLID, EMPL_RCD) in `IMMUN`, how many rows are there in `PS_JOB`? If your answer is 0-1 then you shouldn't have any problem. If your answer is 0-many, then that's the problem.

Comment: I provided sample data Gordon

Comment: #1: As you don 't select any column from the inner table you can simply remove the join to get the expected result. #2: as you partition by `EMPLID` the `ORDER BY EMPLID` will return one of the mathcing rows randomly.

Comment: "sample data" is **not** the result of a query that doesn't meet your requirements. **sample data** should consist of some rows from **each table**.  In addition you should also supply the **expected result**

Answer (score 1):

You are only selecting columns from the first table.  The second table, no doubt, has duplicate matches.

Because you are calculating `rn` in a subquery, you are getting the "first" row along with the multiple matches.

I suspect that your intention may be more along the lines of returning one row from the *second* table (this is just a guess):

```
SELECT ghi.EMPLID, ghi.EMPL_RCD, ghi.EXAM_DT, ghi.IMMUN_CODE
FROM PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN ghi LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT j.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY j.EMPLID, j.EMPL_RCD ORDER BY ?) as seqnum  -- ? because I don't know which column
      FROM PS_JOB j
     ) 
     ON ghi.EMPLID = j.EMPLID AND ghi.EMPL_RCD = j.EMPL_RCD AND j.seqnum = 1
GROUP BY ghiEMPLID, ghi.EXAM_DT, ghi.IMMUN_CODE, ghi.EMPL_RCD
ORDER BY ghi.EXAM_DT;
```

The `GROUP BY` is not necessary for this query.  But it might be needed for the query you are building.

Comment: Gordon I'm curious why you switched the ROW_NUMBER function to be in the PS_JOB table. I believe it needs to remain in the PS_GHS_IMMUN table as I have it. Not really seeing what else should be changed...

Comment: @Nick . . . Without an explanation of what you want to do, it seems like a reasonable interpretation.  But, it is a total guess.